# Fullcalendar time interval

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm using Fullcalendar to show events in my application, but I would also like to use it to schedule resources, but I need to be able to schedule those resources in 5 minute intervals. Can the calendar (week/day view) be configured to render 5 minute timeslots instead of the default 30 minute intervals?

If so, can dragging also be configured at the same interval?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure about the dragging, but as for the calendar... Yes you can change the size of the time slot, in your fullcalendar config include the `slotMinutes` property like,

```
$('#mycalendar').fullcalendar({
    ...
    slotMinutes: 5,
    ...
});
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 18):

In the version [2.3.2](https://github.com/arshaw/fullcalendar/releases/tag/v2.3.2) (I didn't check the previous versions) you can do the following:

```
slotDuration: '00:30:00',
snapDuration: '00:05:00',
```

The **slotDuration** changes the grid display to **30 minutes**.
The **snapDuration** is more interesting: it changes the **start** and **end** times in intervals of **5 minutes** while you're **dragging** the event.

Let's say your event **starts at 10:00 am** and **ends at 10:30 am**. With the above configuration, if you drag the event up (just a little bit) the new times will be: **starts at 10:05 am and ends at 10:35 am**, and so on.

You can find more details at http://fullcalendar.io/docs/agenda/snapDuration/.

Answer (score 13):

I'm using version 2.11 of fullcalendar and to set the interval of 5 minutes, i had to set the slotDuration with format 'hh:mm:ss'

```
$('#mycalendar').fullCalendar({
    ...
    slotDuration: '00:05:00', 
    ...
});
```

Comment: Can i add multiple slotDuration for each resource view in multiple resource view in fullcalendar?